# Populate Page Metadata Schema on selection of Page Template

Tags: metadata, tridion, tridion-2011

In Tridion 2011 - What is the best ways to achieve the below: 
On creation of the new page of editing the existing page, when the editor selects a page template, can we automatically set the associated Page Metadata Schema to it. So basically define a one to one association of a PT and Metadata schema as utilize it.

Comment: Nice question, could we interest you in committing to the [Area 51 Tridion specific proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=gPujQMxthNCNn9xqeeO2NA2). Sign up with the same SO account if you have a moment.

Comment: Done that already Bart :) I fully support

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can see these options:

1. an event handler, see the docs [here](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_C44626C5618242FEAF8B98D2770E7E77) (log in required)
2. a data extender, see the docs [here](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_3B40E7C7F2334D9B9DAD12FA202EFAA7) (log in required)
3. a client-side GUI extension

Each of these extension points has also been covered in previous questions here in StackOverflow and in external blog posts. Those might serve as good additional "documentation" on what is possible/feasible with each of them.

All of these have their own advantages and disadvantages. Which one is best for you really depends on your exact requirements, the willingness you have to educate your users a bit and the skill set of the developers that end up implement and maintaining it.

Event handlers and data extenders run on the server and are written in C#, which means they are typically a bit easier to develop and debug. Client-side GUI extensions give you the fullest control over the user interface, but that control comes at a price: they have a higher learning curve for most developers.

***Update***
To respond to changing of the Page Template in the GUI, you can use something like this:

```js
var c = $display.getView().properties.controls;
$evt.addEventHandler(c.PageTemplate, 'change', function() { 
  console.log(c.PageTemplate.getValue()); // the newly selected Page Template
  c.MetaSchemaDropdown.setValue('tcm:10-2103-8'); // the corresponding Metadata Schema
});
```

Comment: Thanks Frank. Events systems there is nothing like:  OnPagetemplateSelectPre. So this may not be the hook. The second place is data extender and looks like a good hook to place my code and return an extra field called metadata schema for every PT.The issue is anguilla on how to modify metadata schema from what is returned from the Data Extenders. I have a few links on client side anguilla examples and have written a few as well. But haven't gotten any Anguilla example near to this topic i.e. on updating Metadata Schema automatically. If you have or can find any that would be great .

Comment: You can probably create an Anguilla Event Handler that listens to changes on the Page Template dropdown ("change" event), then execute based on this. Do be careful with what you change once the editor has already selected a template, filled in some metadata, then selected a different template (you'll probably overwrite the previous data)

Comment: Regarding the event system: the event that I would check out is the LoadEventArg.

Comment: That would help for the initial value. But when I checked yesterday, no client-to-server call is done when you **change** the Page Template. So it seems doubtful that you can handle an update in a `LoadEventArgs`. Which means that the only option there would be to handle it as a validation call in the save event (http://nunolinhares.blogspot.com/2012/07/validating-content-on-save-part-1-of.html).